# Select many duplicating results

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble with the following method which takes a list long of strings (`big`) and filters it by another list containing the last few characters of the other list (`small`).

```
var big = new List<string> {
    "0000", "1111", "2222", "3333", "3333", "4444", "5555"
};

var small = new List<string> {
    "11", "22", "33", "33", "44"
};

var result = from b in big
from s in small
where b.EndsWith(s)
select b;
```

The expected result is

```
"1111", "2222", "3333", "3333", "4444"
```

The result I'm getting is

```
"1111", "2222", "3333", "3333", "3333", "3333", "4444"
```

I can see why it is happening, but I can't think of a way of how to stop it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why specifically do you expect such a result? As each `"33"` matches both of the `"3333"`, do you want to remove one of the `"33"` from `small` or one of the matched `"3333"` from `big`?

Comment: @Guffa Maybe they're entries from users? User enters X values to be matched against a list to be summed up. idk

Comment: @gunr2171:imho good code samples can explain a reqirement often better than thousand words, all the more if OP is not a native english speaking person. It fulfils also the requirement to show what someone has tried.

Comment: @Bob.: Yes, maybe. Why I want to know is to be able to answer the question for anything else than the specific example. If for example `big` contains three occurances of `"3333"`, would the result have `"3333"` two or three times?

Comment: Question updated with words :)

Comment: @Guffa Thanks for the responses - I'll update the questions further to make clearer your queries. Your query about three `"3333"`s was a situation I hadn't thought of...

Comment: And what if you had "1233" and "2133"? What result would you expect then?

Comment: Hmm okay - bad times all round. I'm going to revert the question back to the original point and accept @TimSchmelter's answer. Thanks for everybody's feedback.

Comment: @dav_i: Next time you can click the _rollback_ -button on a [history revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19274500/revisions). I am glad that i could help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because I made edits so close together SO combined them into one commit so I couldn't rollback what I wanted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query produces a cartesian product, that's why you get repetitions. This works:

```
var result = big.Where(b => small.Any(s => b.EndsWith(s)));
```

or with half query syntax:

```
var result = from b in big
             where small.Any(s => b.EndsWith(s))
             select b;
```

Comment: Won't that return "4444" twice?

Comment: Yes, because OP has changed his sample data, originally no. Now the question makes no sense anymore since it's not clear why 3333 should repeat but not 4444. **Edit** again rollbacked to a previous version ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain what you want, so I'll assume that you want to display the first match in `big` for each word in `small`. You can do it like this:

```
var result=from s in small
           let res=big.FirstOrDefault(s=>b.EndsWith(s))
           where res!=null
           select res;
```

If you want to return the last match, you replace FirstOrDefault with LastOrDefault.

If you want to select the match in some other way, you'll have to explain what you want to achieve